# Como ignorar sentença e caso no .startsWith do Java

Tags: java, if

Esse é meu codigo:

```
if(e.getMessage().startsWith("/reciclar") || e.getMessage().startsWith("/ereciclar")){
e.setCancelled(true);
p.sendMessage("§cComando Bloqueado/Em Manutenção!");
}
```

Porém se usarem /RECICLAR maiúsculo ou em uma sentença diferente Tipo /ReciClaR funciona também, queria saber se da pra ignorar casos no startsWith de uma forma que entre no if()

Comment: Você quer checar se o começoa de uma string começa com `/reciclar`, independente do case do texto, é isso?

Comment: Sim, por que se eu coloca-se equalsIgnoreCase teria forma de adicionar um espaço depois do comando e funcionaria da mesma forma

Comment: Não está muito claro as suas dúvidas, por favor, edite a pergunta e explique um pouco mais

Comment: Acho que resolvi, coloquei para toda vez que alguem tentar usar um comando ele automaticamente diminuir as letras

Comment: Você pode responder com a solução abaixo entao :)

Answer (score 1):

O Java não tem de facto um `startsWith` que ignore maiúsculas e minusculas como tem para o `equals`, que é o `equalsIgnoreCase`.

No entanto é fácil de arranjar uma lógica que consiga fazer isso, convertendo para maiúsculas ou minusculas antes de comparar:

```
String msgMinuscula = e.getMessage().toLowerCase();

if(msgMinuscula.startsWith("/reciclar") || msgMinuscula .startsWith("/ereciclar")){
    e.setCancelled(true);
    p.sendMessage("§cComando Bloqueado/Em Manutenção!");
}
```

É necessário no entanto garantir que o que é colocado no `startsWith` está em minusculas também, caso contrário será necessário converter manualmente caso seja uma `String` colocada á mão ou chamando o método `toLowerCase` caso seja uma variável.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta fazer como abaixo:

`e.getMessage().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("/reciclar")`